# How to use melt() in r for my situation?

Tags: r, melt

I have been trying to use melt() function in r to shape my dataframe.

Here is the original,

```
     group StartX StartY   EndX   EndY id
  18878713 524897 180779 525352 179484  1
  18884056 531199 183111 532538 182503  2
```

I want to shape it to this,

```
     group Variable  Value id
  18878713   524897 180779  1
  18884056   531199 183111  2
  18878713   525352 179484  1
  18884056   532538 182503  2
```

Any idea how I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: `melt` from `data.table v1.9.8` (next release is 1.9.6, shortly, and the one after that) will be able to melt multiple columns. If you want to give it a try, you can use `devtools` to install from the 1.9.8 branch.

Comment: @Arun, I'm waiting for that... Until then, [there's `merged.stack`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26954394/1270695) for the impatient :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another base R solution using `reshape(...)`.

```
result <- reshape(df,idvar=c(1,6),times=c("Start","End"),v.names=c("X","Y"),
                  varying=list(c(2,4),c(3,5)),direction="long")
result
#                    group id  time      X      Y
# 18878713.1.Start 18878713  1 Start 524897 180779
# 18884056.2.Start 18884056  2 Start 531199 183111
# 18878713.1.End   18878713  1   End 525352 179484
# 18884056.2.End   18884056  2   End 532538 182503
```

You can get rid of the `time` column with

```
result$time <- NULL
```

If you insist on using `melt(...)`, which is not really designed for this type of problem, here is one way.

```
library(reshape2)
m.1 <- melt(df,id=c(1,6),measure=c(2,4),value.name="X")
m.2 <- melt(df,id=c(1,6),measure=c(3,5),value.name="Y")
result <- data.frame(m.1[,-3],Y=m.2$Y)
result
#      group id      X      Y
# 1 18878713  1 524897 180779
# 2 18884056  2 531199 183111
# 3 18878713  1 525352 179484
# 4 18884056  2 532538 182503
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(mydf, var.stubs = c("X", "Y"), sep = "var.stubs", atStart = FALSE)
#       group id .time_1      X      Y
# 1: 18878713  1     End 525352 179484
# 2: 18878713  1   Start 524897 180779
# 3: 18884056  2     End 532538 182503
# 4: 18884056  2   Start 531199 183111
```

Generally, it is expected that names are provided in the form of "variable stub" + "sep" + "time value" (for instance, "X.Start", "X.End" and so on). In cases where there is no "sep" you can also specify the "sep" to be a regex of the "var.stubs". The `atStart` argument specifies whether to look for the variable stub at the start or at the end of the variable name.

In this example, you could also specify `sep = "X$|Y$"`, indicating to look for an "X" or a "Y" at the end of the variable names and group those together. In this case, you would not use the `atSart` argument.

---

If you don't want that ".time_1" column, you can use compound statements with `merged.stack`, but note that by removing it, there would be a loss of information in your reshaped data:

```
merged.stack(mydf, var.stubs = c("X", "Y"), sep = "X$|Y$")[, .time_1 := NULL][]
#       group id      X      Y
# 1: 18878713  1 525352 179484
# 2: 18878713  1 524897 180779
# 3: 18884056  2 532538 182503
# 4: 18884056  2 531199 183111
```

---

#### Update: System timings

`merged.stack` is also designed to be pretty fast. Here's a comparison with base R's `reshape` on this dataset replicated to be 1 million rows.

```
## make the dataset 1 million rows
mydf <- do.call(rbind, replicate(500, mydf, FALSE))  ## 1K
mydf <- do.call(rbind, replicate(1000, mydf, FALSE)) ## 1M
mydf$id <- 1:nrow(mydf)                              ## Row-wise id

funMS <- function() merged.stack(mydf, var.stubs = c("X", "Y"), sep = "X$|Y$")

funR <- function() {
  reshape(mydf, idvar = c(1, 6),
          times = c("Start", "End"),
          v.names = c("X", "Y"),
          varying = list(c(2, 4), c(3, 5)),
          direction = "long")
}

system.time(funR())
#    user  system elapsed 
#  23.315   0.000  23.224 
system.time(funMS())
#    user  system elapsed 
#   2.173   0.000   2.207
```

Comment: Ananda, nice! I'm guessing the new feature could be integrated nicely with `merged.stack`?

Comment: @Arun, certainly hoping so :-)

Answer (score 0):

With the new feature to melt multiple columns implemented in `melt.data.table` recently in devel version `v1.9.5`, you can do this:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.5
melt(dt, measure = patterns("^Start", "^End"))[, variable := NULL][]
#       group id value1 value2
# 1: 18878713  1 524897 180779
# 2: 18884056  2 531199 183111
# 3: 18878713  1 525352 179484
# 4: 18884056  2 532538 182503
```

You can install the development version by following [these instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).